Is there a reason no "postscript" tag exists?
Having just asked a question about PostScript, I realized that there's no "postscript" tag yet.
So I wonder: Is there a specific reason?
I don't have enough reputation points here to create the tag.

The short answer: it has not been asked about frequently enough. We only need 150 reps to create one, but there seem to be only 4 highly relevant questions (including yours). So, it is normal not to have one yet. However, I think it's okay to add the postscript tag: Stack Overflow has it, and it is not off-topic for this site. Also, you are actually not far from earning the privilege to add tags. The 150-reputation bar is set because devoted users are more likely to take responsibility for their tags. While we do welcome fine-grained tags, having too many idle tags is not helpful either.
